# Is it possible to initialize static fields within a static function?

Tags: c++, static, lnk2001

I want something that looks like this...:

```
class Foo {
public:
  static void myStaticInit();
  static SomeType myField;
};
```

And inside `.cpp`:

```
#include "SomeOtherFile.h" // contains SomeOtherType

void Foo::myStaticInit() {
  SomeOtherType sot;
  myField = sot.someNonStaticFunction(); // also tried Foo::myField = ...
}
```

... so that I can make calls like `Foo::myField`. But all I get are `LNK2001` errors.

Is such a design possible? Or do I have to provide individual definitions outside a function within `.cpp`?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between initialisation and assignment.

Comment: You have to define your `static` variable.  Add this line after the `Foo` declaration:
`SomeType Foo::myField;`

Comment: @SidS Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `static` variables, you also have to define them.  In your cpp file, after the Foo declaration, add this line:

```
SomeType Foo::myField;
```

Then, your init function should work.

---

Also note that you can initialize it directly by defining it like this:

```
SomeOtherType sot;
SomeType Foo::myField = sot.someNonStaticFunction();
```

or :

```
SomeType Foo::myField = SomeOtherType().someNonStaticFunction();
```